# Install an R package temporarily, only for the current session

Tags: r

Sometimes on Stack Overflow, there's a question relative to a package which is not installed on my system, and which I don't plan to reuse later.

If I install the package with `install.packages()`, it will be put in one of my R install libraries, and then will take some storage space and be updated each time I run `update.packages()`.

Is there a way to install a package only for the current R session ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can install a package temporarily with the following function :

```
tmp.install.packages <- function(pack, dependencies=TRUE, ...) {
  path <- tempdir()
  ## Add 'path' to .libPaths, and be sure that it is not
  ## at the first position, otherwise any other package during
  ## this session would be installed into 'path'
  firstpath <- .libPaths()[1]
  .libPaths(c(firstpath, path))
  install.packages(pack, dependencies=dependencies, lib=path, ...)
}
```

Which you can use simply this way :

```
tmp.install.packages("pkgname")
```

The package is installed in a temporary directory, and its files should be deleted at next system restart (at least on linux systems).

Comment: (+1) I find it useful. I wish you had posted this before I installed like a million packages! :)

Comment: @Arun glad you find this useful, I felt a bit strange to answer my own question...

Comment: @juba why?it is even encouraged. Maybe you need to check if the package is already installed...

Comment: @agstudy Yes, I know... I just saw that I can even accept my own answer after 2 days :)

Comment: @juba You can accept your own answer, but there's no percentage in it.  That is, nobody gets points.  If you accept someone else's answer, you get 2 points and s/he gets 15.  Of course you should only do this if another answer is remotely correct...

Comment: The (major, major) issue with this solution is that R does not support multiple package libraries very well. In particular, this solution will reinstall *all* package dependencies, even if they are already installed on the user's system. This can take a very long time.

Answer (score 10):

Another solution for this problem is `devmode` from `devtools`. Devmode allows you to install packages to a dev repository so your other packages are untouched if you install development versions. For example:

```
library(devtools)
devmode()
install_github('ggplot2', 'hadley')
devmode()
```

You'll notice that your version has not changed.

Comment: yes, but the packages remain installed in the dev_mode, iiuc?

Comment: +1 very useful, as the function I provided doesn't allow to install temporarily with the `devtools` functions such as `install_github`. Thanks !

Comment: @Arun Yes, they do. But they are separated from your regular packages.

Answer (score 9):

`pacman` deals with package management issues like this:

```
library(pacman)
```

Now you can use:

```
p_load("pkgname")   #installs or loads package if already installed
#at end of session:
p_delete("pkgname") #deletes package from lib
```

This is a quick way to install in your directory and then delete it at the end (not really a temporary install)

Comment: But now you have an extra package, `pacman` on your system :-)

Answer (score 5):

As an addition to Tyler's answer a `p_temp` function was recently added to the **pacman** package which does exactly what the question asks for.

```
library(pacman)
p_temp(pkgname) # or p_temp("pkgname") either work...
```

This will install the package and any dependencies temporarily.

Disclosure: Tyler and I are co-authors of the **pacman** package...

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I think a hat tip (even if it's the hat on the dog in your avatar) should go to @juba in the documentation of `p_temp` for the *similarities* between your function and his. If not that, at least a link in the references to this question.

Comment: @AnandaMahto Indeed. I have that in my local version but haven't pushed it to GitHub yet.

Answer (score 0):

The following is something in the middle between
[juba](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14896943/1851270)
and
[sebastian-c](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14897361/1851270),
and is as simple as that:

```
.libPaths("/my/path")
```

Now and until the end of the *current session*,
you can install packages as you normally would, and they will end up in
`/my/path`.

Also package *dependencies* will go to `/my/path`.
If you want to have control over dependencies, you can specify them manually with:

```
install.packages(c("pack", "dep1", "dep2", ...), dependencies = FALSE)
```

This approach might be useful in two particular scenarios:

- A so-to-say discovery session. You want to discover new packages and install them casually to see if something interesting pops up. Then, you use an OS provided tempdir in `.libPaths()`, to avoid messing your R setup, and the OS will take care of the cleaning.
- Create, nowadays common, *reproducible environments*.
  You install a base R, then add `.libPaths("my/project/dir")`. By looking at this dir, you have a clear picture of what are your project package requirements. Further, you can copy this folder to another PC to reproduce the same environment. Much like Python [pipenv](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) you can have more isolated environments: for each session, you call `.libPaths()` with the related project dir.