# How to build and reload a package (for development) in R without overwriting its CRAN version?

Tags: r, rstudio, cran

I'm contributing to an R package in github, which I clone to my machine and make changes in Rstudio. When I use `Build and reload`, the package is built and installed to my default library, overwriting the stable, installed-from-CRAN version of the package.

How do I maintain two versions of this package, so that my development work on the package does not interfere with my analysis using the package?

Comment: `devtools::dev_mode()` should do the trick, though I'll need to check again whether it's respected by build and reload. It should be in theory!

Comment: @NickK The output of `Build and Reload` suggests that it's still installing to my default library. Great pointer towards `dev_mode` though!

Comment: Take a look at the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896941/install-an-r-package-temporarily-only-for-the-current-session.

Comment: @Heisenberg it's supposed to. See https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486508-Building-Testing-and-Distributing-Packages Maybe there's a bug?

Comment: I filed a bug report. We'll see.