# Problems with installing any packages in Rstudio

Tags: r, installation, syntax-error, rstudio

I have a problem installing any packages in Rstudio, here are some screenshots of code and results(mistakes)

[image]

then it's written that it's not writable

[image]

then there is a question: do you want to create your own library ? yes

[image]

and then i get this error:

```
cannot create dir 'C:\Users\darya\OneDrive\?????????', reason 'Invalid argument'
Error in install.packages : unable to create ‘C:/Users/darya/OneDrive/?????????/R/win-library/4.1’
```

How can I fix it ?

Comment: While it might be feasible to have a library-directory of packages maintained on OneDrive, *installing* packages into it has proven problematic for a lot of people. The resolution I've found has always been to not try to install packages into OneDrive, instead [installing to a temporary location](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14896941/3358272) and when complete, moving that new package directory into a more permanent location (perhaps your OneDrive).

Comment: To add, I would say I don't really see the point of wanting to install packages into a OD location. If the concern is loss of packages, I'd assume that most packages are readily available out there (CRAN, Bioconductor, Github). Point is, I wouldn't treat packages in the same way one would treat files like data files, Office docs, R scripts, etc. To answer your question directly, you can fix your problem by saving the packages outside of OD.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.